# Finding a button by the span text in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
<li id="b43d980c-53bb-4892-8f32-5ae8ebd9026e" class="">
        <input type="button">
        <span>Male</span>
      </li>
```

How can I locate this and then click on it?

Comment: Try xpath: `"//span[text()='Male']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='button']"`

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Male']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='button']"))).click() This is the code I used to try and click it. Doesn't seem to click it. I know when it's selected as the tick appears.

Answer (score 0):

Text() attribute in xpath locator should do the trick to find the span:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//span[text()='Male']"))
```

Want to grab the input before?

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//span[text()='Male']/preceding-sibling::input"))
```

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Male']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='button']"))).click()
 This is the code I used to try and click it. Doesn't seem to click it. I know when it's selected as the tick appears.

Comment: are you sure there are no other span's with text of "male" that might be getting selected.